# How to calculate Online Video Gaming Bandwith Requirement

Tags: stream

Imagine i have a server which will have hardware to play games on it and it will stream the game itself to the client. Client also will send controls(keyboard & mouse) to the server. (Like Nvidia Grid).

How can i calculate the bandwith required(approximate) on client?
(Game video should be uncompressed)

For example;

-1080p @120Fps
-2K @60Fps

I just want to know how can i calculate(Math behind it) the bandwith requirement(Video+Controls). I know uncompressed video will require huge bandwith.

Comment: This depends, how is it being compressed etc. Just do what Hobo said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncompressed...

1920*1080*60*3 (24bit color) per frame = 373248000 bytes/sec. For video.

Over 2Gb/sec. Assuming a raw datagram.